# Is a set with two collinear vectors always linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Say you have $\vec v_1 =\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ $\vec v_2 =\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec v_3 =$ anything.

Is the set  $\{\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3\}$ always considered linearly dependent because $\{\vec v_1, \vec v_2\}$ is?

Comment: Yes. That plainly y simply follows from the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement for linear dependence is that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3=0$, where not *all* the $a$s are zero. So if $a_1=a_2$ and $a_3=0$, then that would make it zero, so yes, they will always be linearly dependent

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check by the definition:

$$1\cdot \vec{v_1}+1\cdot \vec{v_2} +0\cdot \vec{v_3} =\vec0$$

and not all the coefficients are zero, thus there is lin. dependence.